SQL aggregation based on time
I'm trying to calculate how much time people spent on an area. For this we have node_address representing a person, the areaName and the time when the person was seen.
Original Data



date
areaName
node_address/person




8:15
area1
1


8:20
area1
1


8:25
area1
1


8:30
area1
1


8:45
area1
1


9:00
area1
1


8:15
area2
2


8:20
area2
2


9:00
area2
1


9:05
area2
2


9:10
area2
2



Expected Data
areaName | time
area1    | 25 min
area2    | 15 min

this times are justified by the following conditions:
The person 1 was inside area1 from 8:15 to 8:30 - 15 minutes (since was seen in intervals of less than 10 minutes), also was seen at 8:45 - 5 minutes (its considered to be 5 minutes since it was seen only one time, no other records less than 10 minutes away), 9:00 - 5 minutes.
The same for the person 2, was inside area2 from 8:15 to 8:20 - 5 minutes , and was seen from 9:00 to 9:10 - 10 minutes.
I was able to develop a query to get the difference time to the previous time and to the next time, also I do a verification to check if its comparing the same person:
SELECT
        date,
        node_address,
        areaName,
        CASE
            WHEN node_address = LAG(node_address) OVER (ORDER BY areaName, node_address, date)
            THEN DATETIME_DIFF(date, LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY areaName, node_address, date), MINUTE)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS PrevDiff,
        CASE
            WHEN node_address = LEAD(node_address) OVER (ORDER BY areaName, node_address, date)
            THEN DATETIME_DIFF(LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY areaName, node_address, date), date, MINUTE)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS NextDiff
    FROM . . .

(but I was unable to find a solution to make this calculations)

Removed conflicting database product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use

Create some data to work with.
-- Simulate the input data into a table called NodeAddresses.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NodeAddresses;
CREATE TABLE NodeAddresses(area_date DATETIME NOT NULL
                                , area_name CHAR(5) NOT NULL
                                , node_address BIGINT NOT NULL
                                );
                                
INSERT INTO NodeAddresses(area_date
                        , area_name
                        , node_address
                        )
VALUES ('2024-01-01 08:15:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:20:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:25:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:30:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:45:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 09:00:00', 'area1', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:15:00', 'area2', 2)
    , ('2024-01-01 08:20:00', 'area2', 2)
    , ('2024-01-01 09:00:00', 'area2', 1)
    , ('2024-01-01 09:05:00', 'area2', 2)
    , ('2024-01-01 09:10:00', 'area2', 2);

Find the previous date, and next date, for each node address and area. Use this to calculate the time differences in that area for that node address. Adjust the time differences according to your 10 minute interval condition. Determine the sum of these times, for each area.
SELECT subq3.area_name
    , SUM(subq3.minutes_spent_in_area) AS total_minutes_in_area
FROM(
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN (minutes_since_previous >= 10 OR minutes_since_previous IS NULL) AND (minutes_till_next >= 10 OR minutes_till_next IS NULL)
                THEN 5
            WHEN minutes_since_previous >= 10
                THEN 0
            ELSE minutes_since_previous
        END AS minutes_spent_in_area
        , area_name
    FROM(
        SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, previous_area_date, area_date) AS minutes_since_previous
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, area_date, next_area_date) AS minutes_till_next
            , area_name
        FROM(
            SELECT area_date
                , LAG(area_date) OVER(PARTITION BY node_address, area_name ORDER BY area_date ASC) AS previous_area_date
                , LEAD(area_date) OVER(PARTITION BY node_address, area_name ORDER BY area_date ASC) AS next_area_date
                , area_name
                , node_address
            FROM NodeAddresses
            ) subq
        ) subq2
    ) subq3
GROUP BY subq3.area_name;




area_name
total_minutes_in_area




area1
25


area2
15



Try it yourself: db<>fiddle

Hello, I have implemented that solution and after some testing it returns the correct data. Thanks for the reply I will use this solution.

@AndreCoelhoo, happy to hear that you have solved your problem. Good luck.

WITH 
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `node_address/person` ORDER BY `date`) - 1) DIV 2 rn
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT areaName, `node_address/person`,
         MIN(`date`) date_in, MAX(`date`) date_out
  FROM cte1
  GROUP BY areaName, `node_address/person`, rn
  )
SELECT areaName, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(date_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(date_in))) total
FROM cte2
GROUP BY areaName;




areaName
total




area1
00:25:00


area2
00:10:00



detailed fiddle

    WITH RankedRecords AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        areaName,
        node_address,
        LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY areaName, node_address ORDER BY date) AS prev_date,
        LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY areaName, node_address ORDER BY date) AS next_date
    FROM your_table
), SessionBoundaries AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        areaName,
        node_address,
        prev_date,
        next_date,
        CASE
            WHEN prev_date IS NULL OR DATE_DIFF(date, prev_date, MINUTE) > 10 THEN 'start'
            WHEN next_date IS NULL OR DATE_DIFF(next_date, date, MINUTE) > 10 THEN 'end'
            ELSE 'middle'
        END AS session_boundary
    FROM RankedRecords
), SessionDurations AS (
    SELECT
        areaName,
        node_address,
        SUM(duration) AS total_time_spent
    FROM (
        SELECT
            areaName,
            node_address,
            CASE
                WHEN session_boundary IN ('start', 'end') THEN 5 -- Single record session or end of multi-record session
                WHEN LEAD(session_boundary) OVER (PARTITION BY areaName, node_address ORDER BY date) = 'end' THEN
                    DATE_DIFF(LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY areaName, node_address ORDER BY date), date, MINUTE)
                ELSE 0 -- Middle of a session, duration will be calculated at the end of the session
            END AS duration
        FROM SessionBoundaries
    ) AS durations
    GROUP BY areaName, node_address
), AggregatedAreaTimes AS (
    SELECT
        areaName,
        SUM(total_time_spent) AS total_time
    FROM SessionDurations
    GROUP BY areaName
)
SELECT areaName, total_time || ' min' AS time FROM AggregatedAreaTimes;


Hello, I have implemented that solution, although it works, it considers that if I get from 8:10 to 8:20 the time is 15 minutes instead of 10 minutes. Thanks for the reply I was able to resolve this.

Here's a less terse solution that intentionally postpones the group by area until the last moment.
sqlfiddle
I've found this technique indispensable when confronted with similar requirements in the past, when the need inevitably arises to browse the data line by line, unpicking the logic applied at each step, and reporting in both aggregated and un-aggregated states.
It also returns the correct value of 15 mins for area2, which I notice a few of the solutions above do not.
I've written it for SQL Server, but can be easily translated to other dialects.
Bear with me as I explain it step by step in the comments below :)
/*
    record sample data in temp table, with row_number() for self join below
*/
create table #PeopleInArea (r int, [date] time, areaName varchar(10), [node_address/person] int)
insert into #PeopleInArea (r, [date], areaName, [node_address/person])
select 
    row_number() over(order by areaName, [date]) as r, 
    x.*
from
(
    select '8:15' as [date], 'area1' as areaName, 1 as [node_adress/person]
    union all select '8:20', 'area1', 1
    union all select '8:25', 'area1', 1
    union all select '8:30', 'area1', 1
    union all select '8:45', 'area1', 1
    union all select '9:00', 'area1', 1
    union all select '8:15', 'area2', 2
    union all select '8:20', 'area2', 2
    union all select '9:00', 'area2', 1
    union all select '9:05', 'area2', 2
    union all select '9:10', 'area2', 2
) x


/*
    self join, to show each sighting against the previous sighting, for a particular person in a given area
*/
select
    pa.*, 
    pa2.r as [lastRow],
    pa2.[date] as lastDate,
    pa2.areaName as lastArea,
    datediff([minute], pa2.[date], pa.[date]) as timeSinceLast,
    pa2.[node_address/person] as lastNodePerson,
    case 
        when datediff([minute], pa2.[date], pa.[date]) < 10
            and pa2.areaName = pa.areaName
            and pa2.[node_address/person] = pa.[node_address/person]
        then 1 else 0 
    end as IsConsecutive    /* sighting of particular person in a given area follows consecutively, within last 10 mins, a previous sighting of that person in the same area */
into #lastSightings
from #PeopleInArea pa
    left join #PeopleInArea pa2 on 
    (
        pa.areaName = pa2.areaName
        and pa.[node_address/person] = pa2.[node_address/person]
        and pa.r = pa2.r + 1
    )

--select * from #lastSightings order by pa.areaName, pa.[node_address/person], pa.[date]


/*
    identify consecutive sightings, create a unique identifier for each
*/
select y.*,
    sum(IsBlockStart) over(order by areaName, [node_address/person], [date]) as BlockId     /* distinguish consecutive blocks of one or more sightings of a particular person in a given area */
into  #ConsecutiveBlocks
from
(
    select x.*,
        case 
            when 
                [lastRow] is null 
                or lastArea != areaName
                or [lastNodePerson] != [node_address/person] 
                or timeSinceLast > 10
            then 1 else 0
        end as IsBlockStart     /* 1 when particular sighting is the first in a sequence or 1 or more sightings, of a particular person in a given area */
    from #lastSightings x
    --order by areaName, [node_address/person], [date]
) y
-- order by areaName, [node_address/person], [date]

--select * from #ConsecutiveBlocks order by areaName, [node_address/person], [date]

/*
    apply business logic, re amount of time allocated to a given sighting

        1. A particular person sighted consecutively in a given area over intervals less than 10 minutes apart is attributed the full duration, i.e. duration since the last sighting of that person in that area.
        2. A particular person sighted in a given area only once in a 10 minute interval is considered to have been there for exactly 5 minutes.
*/
select
    cb.*,
    case        /* consecutive sightings within 10 mins of each other are attributed their full duration */
        when IsConsecutive = 1 and timeSinceLast < 10 then timeSinceLast
        when    /* isolated sightings are attributed 5 mins only */
            IsBlockStart = 1
            and (not exists (select 1 from #ConsecutiveBlocks cbx where cbx.BlockId = cb.BlockId and cbx.IsConsecutive = 1))
        then 5
    end as consecutiveTime
into #ConsecutiveTime
from #ConsecutiveBlocks cb

-- select * from #ConsecutiveTime order by areaName, [node_address/person], [date]

/*
    aggregate total time spent by given person in given area
*/
select
    areaName,
    sum(consecutiveTime) as [time]
from #ConsecutiveTime 
group by areaName
order by areaName

BTW I've left a few lines commented intentionally, to ensure anyone picking through this code in future is inspecting it with the most helpful order by clauses available to them at each step.
Results
Pre-Aggregation



r
date
areaName
node_address/person
lastRow
lastDate
lastArea
timeSinceLast
lastNodePerson
IsConsecutive
IsBlockStart
BlockId
consecutiveTime




1
08:15:00
area1
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
1
1
NULL


2
08:20:00
area1
1
1
08:15:00
area1
5
1
1
0
1
5


3
08:25:00
area1
1
2
08:20:00
area1
5
1
1
0
1
5


4
08:30:00
area1
1
3
08:25:00
area1
5
1
1
0
1
5


5
08:45:00
area1
1
4
08:30:00
area1
15
1
0
1
2
5


6
09:00:00
area1
1
5
08:45:00
area1
15
1
0
1
3
5


9
09:00:00
area2
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
1
4
5


7
08:15:00
area2
2
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
1
5
NULL


8
08:20:00
area2
2
7
08:15:00
area2
5
2
1
0
5
5


10
09:05:00
area2
2
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
1
6
NULL


11
09:10:00
area2
2
10
09:05:00
area2
5
2
1
0
6
5



Post-Aggregation



areaName
time




area1
25


area2
15




This is a gaps and islands problem, it can be solved by calculating the cumulative sum of the differences between the current and previous timestamps to assign a distinct group identifier.
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
                          LAG(`date`, 1, `date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `node_address/person` ORDER BY `date`),
                          `date`
                          ) as diff
  FROM test
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN diff <= 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY `node_address/person` ORDER BY `date`) AS grp
  FROM CTE
)
SELECT areaName, SUM(CASE WHEN diff > 5 THEN 5 ELSE diff END) AS `time`
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY areaName;

Results :
areaName    time
area1       25
area2       15

Demo here
